# Checking files in a different folder using for loop

Tags: shell-script

I have 2 folder - folder1 and folder2.

Im in folder1 and need to execute a shellscript that will search for all the csv files in folder2..

The current script check *.csv in the current folder..how to point to folder2?

```
for file in *.csv
do
  split -l 50000 -d -a 4  "$file" "$file"
done
```

Answer (score 5):

Assuming both `folder1` and `folder2` are under `parent` folder,

```
parent
   folder1
   folder2
```

You can rephrase your for loop as,

```
for file in ../folder2/*.csv
```

As a general rule, you can always give absolute paths to such loops:

```
for file in /home/username/parent/folder2/*.csv
do
    split -l 50000 -d -a 4  "$file" "$file"
done
```

The loop above will work irrespective of which directory you happen to be in.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `pushd` and `popd` whenever you need to change directory for some operations and then change it back to the original.

```
pushd /path/to/folder2
for file in *.csv
do
  split -l 50000 -d -a 4  "$file" "$file"
done
popd
```